Drawtext error FFMPEG 7
I upgraded to ffmpeg 7 and now drawtext is no longer found. I already had --enable-libfreetype and was working fine with ffmpeg 6.
I tried to add --enable-libharfbuzz from Gyan's answer here
But then ffmpeg still won't compile. stating that harfbuzz in not in the pkg-config.
How do you compile libharfbuzz to work with ffmpeg? I can't find any docs for it.

Which platform? What toolchain?

You read the comment on that answer? "also needed to install libharfbuzz-dev before : !apt-get install -y libharfbuzz-dev"

@Gyan thanks for responding. I actually got it working. I did the configure / make install etc and then --enable-libharfbuzz like the other libs and it worked fine. I was going of the site and they were installing it with Pip but I think that is for standalone and not with FFMPEG.
